# get time in milliseconds

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hii,

How to get time in milliseconds in ros? I am using ROS Indigo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257021/get-time-in-milliseconds/) by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on ROS Answers with karma: 272 on 2017-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Time

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ros::Time has a method **toNSec()** and public attribute **nsec**.

---

Originally posted by [hauff](https://answers.ros.org/users/28345/hauff/) with karma: 11 on 2018-12-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1